# MSSQL SSIS is disable but Scale Out Master service is still running. Can and how to disable this

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to clean up all unnecessary services on our DB boxes, therefore have disabled most of the SQL related features like SSIS and reporting etc. However it appears a sql process for is still running: "Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.WorkerAgentServiceHost.exe".

Based on investigations this appears to be a process for the "Scale Out Master service" which appears to be part of SSIS.

My questions: given we have disabled SSIS

- can I safely disable this process?
- where is the correct place to do this?

To clarify, I know I could manage this in "Services" but most other SQL related services have management options in SQL Configuration, but I cannot see anything there and I would have expected disabling SSIS might have also disabled this Scale Out master too?

TIA